# How to get and export data from column in datatable in jsf

Tags: jsf, export-to-csv

Hello i have this table [image: table]My question is how to make when i click the button in last column to export only the text in the column Report text for the current row where is the button

Source code of the button

```
public void export() {
        try {
            FastReportBuilder report = new FastReportBuilder();

            report
                    .addColumn(MessageUtil.getMessage("Report text"), "DAILY_FISCAL_REPORTS.reportText}", String.class.getName(), 45)

                    .setPrintColumnNames(true)
                    .setIgnorePagination(true)
                    .setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                     report.getColumn(2).setTextFormatter(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT);

            DynamicReport dr = report.build();
            JRDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(packs);
            JasperPrint jp = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(dr, new ClassicLayoutManager(), ds);
            Util.exportToHttpStream(jp, MessageFormat.format("Incaso_search_{0}.xlsx", DATE_FORMAT_FILE_NAME.format(new Date())), true);

        } catch (ColumnBuilderException | ClassNotFoundException | IOException | JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VpExportFormatter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "There was error while generating search report", ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried with fast report builder but i'm doing something wrong,i will edit with the source of the button

Comment: How can i using bufferedwriter to export in txt file this content

Comment: I don't see anything PrimeFaces related here